# Converting multiple tab-delimited .txt files into multiple .xls files

Tags: python, csv, xls, xlwt

I am a newbie to python and I am trying to do what the title above says with the code displayed below. It runs up to the point where I ask to save the xls output. Any help would be very much appreciated.

```
import glob
import csv
import xlwt

for filename in glob.glob("C:\xxxx\*.txt"):
    wb = xlwt.Workbook()
    sheet = wb.add_sheet('sheet 1')
    newName = filename
    spamReader = csv.reader(open(filename, 'rb'), delimiter=';',quotechar='"')
    for rowx, row in enumerate(spamReader):
        for colx, value in enumerate(row):
            sheet.write(rowx, colx, value)

    wb.save(newName + ".xls")

print "Done"

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/Aline/Desktop/Python_tests/1st_trial.py", line 13, in <module>
wb.save("C:\Users\Aline\Documents\Data2013\consulta_cand_2010\newName.xls")
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\xlwt\Workbook.py", line 662, in save
doc.save(filename, self.get_biff_data())
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\xlwt\Workbook.py", line 637, in get_biff_data
shared_str_table   = self.__sst_rec()
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\xlwt\Workbook.py", line 599, in __sst_rec
return self.__sst.get_biff_record()
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\xlwt\BIFFRecords.py", line 76, in get_biff_record
self._add_to_sst(s)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\xlwt\BIFFRecords.py", line 91, in _add_to_sst
u_str = upack2(s, self.encoding)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\xlwt\UnicodeUtils.py", line 50, in upack2
us = unicode(s, encoding)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc7 in position 4: ordinal not in    range(128)
```

[edit]
This code works.

```
import glob
import csv
import xlwt

for filename in glob.glob("C:\\Users\\Aline\\Documents\\Data2013\\consulta_cand_2010\\*.txt"):
    spamReader = csv.reader((open(filename, 'rb')), delimiter=';',quotechar='"')
    encoding = 'latin1'
    wb = xlwt.Workbook(encoding=encoding)
    sheet=xlwt.Workbook()
    sheet = wb.add_sheet('sheet 1')
    newName = filename
    for rowx, row in enumerate(spamReader):
        for colx, value in enumerate(row):
            sheet.write(rowx, colx, value)
    wb.save(newName + ".xls")

print "Done"
```

Comment: And the output diverges from your expectation how?

Comment: @Lazarus, thanks for your reply. I get the above traceback and I'm using Python 2.7.

Comment: From the error it seems as if the file contains certain characters (0xc7) which is causing error. So you can first replace those characters with a blank or anything which has an ascii value of less than 128.

Comment: @himanshushekhar, many thanks for your reply. Yes, it might be causing the problem. The txt files I am reading contain some words in Portuguese. Do you know how I can replace those characters not recognized or a way of making Python read them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your encoding needs to be set for the output spreadsheet, I believe.  You'd need to know what encoding that file is using.  The csv module does not directly support unicode, but it's `[8-bit-clean][1]` so it just works for most western languages.

Without knowing what the encoding of your text file is, you have two options.  Option 1 is use your local encoding according to python:

```
   >>> import locale
   >>> lang_code, encoding = locale.getdefaultlocale()
```

^^ Be careful using getdefaultlocale(). The documentation states that encoding **MAY BE None**.

**OR** just fallback to UTF8 and cross your fingers :D.

```
   >>> encoding = 'UTF8'
   >>> workbook = xlwt.Workbook(encoding=encoding)
```

Comment: Jaime, thank you very much to take the time to answer. The second option solved my problem, but I replaced UTF8 by latin1.

Answer (score 0):

You're not escaping the file names.  For example, in Python the string `"consulta_cand_2010\newName.xls"` has `"\n"` in the middle, which is an end-of-line character --- invalid for a file name!

On Windows you need to write the literal strings containing file names `"C:\\Like\\This"` or `"C:/Like/This"` or even `r"C:\Like\This"`.

Comment: Many thanks for your reply. I have corrected the paths, but I still get the same problem. As @himanshushekhar suggests above, there is an error coming from some portuguese characters not recognized by Python in the input file. Any ideas on how to solve this would be very much appreciated.