# How to change automatically the type of the excel file from Tab space separated Text to xls file?

Tags: python, linux, excel, shell, xlrd

I have **an excel file** whose extension is **.xls** but his type is **Tab Space separated Text**.

When I try to open the file by MS Excel it tells me that the extension is fake. And So I have to confirm that I trust the file and so I can read it then.

But my real problem is that when I try to read my file by the **xlrd library** it gives me this message :

**`xlrd.biffh.XLRDError: Unsupported format, or corrupt file: Expected BOF record;`**

And so to resolve this problem, I go to **Save as** in MS Excel and I change the type **manually** to .xls.

But my boss insist that I have to do this by code. I have 3 choices : **Shell script under Linux**, **.bat file under Windows** or **Python**.

So, how can I **change the type of the excel file from Tab space separated Text to xls file by Shell script (command line), .bat or Python?**

Comment: I know you haven't tagged this `perl`, but still... See [Excel::Writer::XLSX](https://metacpan.org/module/Excel::Writer::XLSX)

Comment: Hi @devnull! Well, I code in Python. I didn't code in Perl, neither the libray AFAI in Perl. Here the link to downloading it : https://pypi.python.org/pypi/xlrd .

Comment: Try the answer in this link:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17110674/converting-multiple-tab-delimited-txt-files-into-multiple-xls-files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **real** type of the file is dictated by the contents of the file, not the name of it.  `xlrd` doesn't care about the name at all, it cares about the contents, so `xlrd` is not your problem, and it's not even relevant to your task.

I don't know what you mean by "tab space separated text".  Are the values separated by `'\t '` (a tab character followed by a space character)?  Sometimes tabs and sometimes spaces?

If the separator is constant, just use Python's [`csv`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) module.  If the separator is whitespace and the data does **not** contain whitespace, then you can use Python's [`split()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) string method.  If the separator varies *and* can appear in the data, then you will have to write something fancier to parse it.

In any case, once you have read the data, to write out a **real** `.xls` file, your best Python option is the [`xlwt`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/xlwt) module.

Comment: Well, even if this is not completely the answer, but you are right in saying "it cares about the content" and not about the name... and so I read it by codecs module of Python. Thanks

Comment: It's not "completely the answer" only because you haven't provided "completely the question". You never clarified what "tab space separated text" is. I have no idea why you would need the `codecs` module. I think you are making it much harder for yourself than it needs to be.

Comment: it's a text which use "Tab space" as a separator between the cells of the same line.

Comment: Do you mean a tab character followed by a space character?  Then just use the `csv` module, with `delimiter='\t '`.

Answer (score 1):

mv file.{xls,csv}

It's a csv file, stop treating it as an excel file and things will work a lot better. :)  There are nice csv manipulation tools available in most languages. Do you really need the excel library?

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your answer, I already tried this command, but it didn't work... Being hopeless, I'm going to use the native splitting instead of xlrd... I wanted to win time but... And well, .xls is an obligation because it will be used in an application as an input