# Convert .txt to .xls from nested folders

Tags: python, excel

I found a Python script to convert .txt to .xls and it is working: [Converting multiple tab-delimited .txt files into multiple .xls files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17110674/converting-multiple-tab-delimited-txt-files-into-multiple-xls-files) :

```
import glob
    import csv
    import xlwt
    import win32com.client as win32
for filename in glob.glob("C:\Users\MSI\Desktop\Python Lab\AGR\\*.txt"):
    spamReader = csv.reader((open(filename, 'rb')), delimiter='|',quotechar='"')
    encoding = 'latin1'
    wb = xlwt.Workbook(encoding=encoding)

    sheet=xlwt.Workbook()
    sheet = wb.add_sheet('sheet 1')
    newName = filename
    for rowx, row in enumerate(spamReader):
        for colx, value in enumerate(row):
            sheet.write(rowx, colx, value)

    wb.save(newName.replace('.txt','.xls'))

print "Done"
```

However, it can only convert the file path but could not convert any files in nested folders.

How I may modify it to include nested folders?

Answer (score 1):

Something like the following should work. It uses Python's [`os.walk`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html?highlight=os.walk#os.walk) function to traverse all sub folders:

```
import xlwt
import os

path = r'C:\Users\MSI\Desktop\Python Lab\AGR'

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
    for filename in files:
        name, ext = os.path.splitext(filename)
        if ext.lower() == '.txt':
            source = os.path.join(root, filename)
            dest = os.path.join(root, name + '.xls')

            with open(source, 'rb') as f_input:
                spamReader = csv.reader(f_input, delimiter='|',quotechar='"')
                wb = xlwt.Workbook(encoding='latin1')
                sheet = xlwt.Workbook()
                sheet = wb.add_sheet('sheet 1')

                for rowx, row in enumerate(spamReader):
                    for colx, value in enumerate(row):
                        sheet.write(rowx, colx, value)

                wb.save(dest)

print "Done"
```

Comment: Hi Martin, thanks for your code. I am a newbie in Python programming and when I executed your code, I received error "IdentationError: unexpected indent". May you be of help. Million thanks.

Comment: The code above should work fine, but you should copy/paste it to ensure the indenting remains identical to what is there. Python is very sensitive to this. Also make sure you do not mix tab characters with space characters, this is what normally causes the problem.