# Convert text files to Microsoft Excel that can accommodate more than 65536 rows

Tags: python, excel

I found [Python code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17110674/converting-multiple-tab-delimited-txt-files-into-multiple-xls-files) (as below) to convert text files to Microsoft Excel and it works. However 65,536 is the maximum number of spreadsheet rows supported by Excel 97, Excel 2000, Excel 2002 and Excel 2003 whereas Excel 2007, 2010 and 2013 support 1,048,576 rows.

Since my text files contain more than 65,536 rows, how do I modify the code so that it could work best to convert text files to Excel versions that can cater for 1,048,576 rows?

```
import glob
import csv
import xlwt

for filename in glob.glob("C:\Users\MSI\Desktop\Line Item Besar\\*.txt"):
    spamReader = csv.reader((open(filename, 'rb')), delimiter='|',quotechar='"')
    encoding = 'latin1'
    wb = xlwt.Workbook(encoding=encoding)
    sheet=xlwt.Workbook()
    sheet = wb.add_sheet('sheet 1')
    newName = filename
    for rowx, row in enumerate(spamReader):
        for colx, value in enumerate(row):
            sheet.write(rowx, colx, value)
    wb.save(newName.replace('.txt','.xls'))

print "Done"
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to save your file as `.xlsx`, a modern `XML`-like format that is now used instead of old binary `.xls`. However, there are several questions on SO stating that `xlwt` doesn't work with `.xlsx`, so probably you have to switch to another module, for example [`XlsxWriter`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/XlsxWriter).

Answer (score 0):

[XlsxWriter](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.org/index.html) and [OpenPyXL](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) support creating Excel xlxs files with 1 million rows.

Here is a version of your program using XlsxWriter:

```
import glob
import csv
from xlsxwriter import Workbook

for filename in glob.glob("C:\path\*.txt"):
    spamReader = csv.reader((open(filename, 'rb')),
                            delimiter='|', quotechar='"')

    newName = filename.replace('.txt', '.xlsx')

    workbook = Workbook(newName, {'strings_to_numbers': True})
    worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

    for rowx, row in enumerate(spamReader):
        for colx, value in enumerate(row):
            worksheet.write(rowx, colx, value)

    workbook.close()

print "Done"
```

Comment: Hi jmcnamara. Thanks for your code, however I received SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape. May you please advise. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to ensure that any data read from the txt files using the `csv` module is converted to UTF-8. See the documentation for the `csv` module on [how to handle Unicode CSV data](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#examples).